# JSON - do i need properties with "false"?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a big JSON file with one big Array (now over 50KB).
Each elemet of the Array consist of ~ 20 properties and many of them are just like:

```
"xy":"false"
```

So now my thought is to delete all these false props and just keep the true one's. Is that a common way to do? Is there a big "performance or whatever" difference if i check for true/undefiened or true/false?

Comment: You could still use 0 and 1 to define true false

Comment: Depends entirely on what you're doing with the data. How you're loading it. Etc..

Comment: This is all up to you.  There is no correct answer here.  If you remove the "false" properties, will that affect your program?  Does it expect to have all the properties or will it know what's missing?

Comment: It depends on how client application behaves with JSON result. If JSON is a response from the server, client should take care of unavailable fields.

Comment: Technically "false" is true...

Comment: do you want the string `"false"` or the boolean `false`?

Comment: damn it i didn't recognized that false without "" is the boolean value :D and i was wondering why i have to check for "false" in my script haha - that happens when you start from zero and just start to do things . . . so basicly "xy":0 or "xy":1 will do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have arrays, but rather *objects* (given the `"xy":"false"` property initializer you've shown).

If you're okay with the semantic change (a property that isn't there *isn't there*, it's not `false` [or `"false"`]), then sure, it's fine. If your properties' values are really `false` (rather than `"false"` as shown in the question), then doing something like:

```
if (deserializedObject.xy) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

...will take the `else` route for `false` or a property that doesn't exist (in JavaScript; given your tags I assume you're consuming this JSON with JavaScript).

But there is a difference, hence my comment about semantics. For instance:

```
if ("xy" in deserializedObject) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

...will follow the `if` block with your current data, but the `else` block if you remove the property, as will `deserializedObject.hasOwnProperty("xy")`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

I mean, yes, you'll undeniably have a performance gain by having less data be sent.

But is it worth it...? Possibly. Personally, I reserve such "optimisations" for cases where the file may be called many, many times by many users, as a 10-or-so byte change multiplied by a million requests in a day is 10Mb, or 300Mb in a month, and that's just for one property. So the potential savings is huge.

Most of the time, however, it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading you correctly, your JSON is one big array of objects and each object has ~20 properties . . . is that correct?

If so, it **should** be relatively easy just to leave out any properties that would be set to `false`.  At that point, you could simply rely on some code like this to check for the "true/false" property that you want:

```
if (jsonValue[currentObjectindex].hasOwnProperty("nameOfProperty") {
    . . . do stuff for the "true" state . . .
}
else {
    . . . do stuff for the "false" state . . .
}
```

Of course that will only work if you are ***sure*** that these properties will only exist in the object, when true.  Otherwise you would also have to a check for your `true` value, in situations where the property exists.

Depending on how many `false` properties there are in a given object, the result could be a considerably smaller JSON structure.